# Elements of a sparse matrix

Tags: sparse-matrix

A sparse matrix is a matrix populated with zero elements. All the elements of a sparse matrix are being "**INDEPENDENT**". Unfortunately I didn't understand what was meant by the term "Independent". In other words, why the elements of a sparse matrix are independent? What is the motivation? Kindly if you can give me brief simple examples..

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the elements are not dependent on each other. Ie, each element in the matrix is independent of one another.
Assuming a matrix [[0,3],[4,1]]

There is no relation between the 4 elements in this matrix.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But why? what is the motivation that the elements of a sparse matrix are not dependent

Comment: Can you please provide the link to where you have this